# Why &nbsp replace as A in excel while scrape data from website in python , I am trying to solve it with .replace('&nbsp;',"") but still not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, export-to-excel

I am using python, Here is my code and screenshot
[image]

```
Category = soup.find('a', class_='article-labels__text b-reith-sans-font').text.replace('&nbsp;',"").replace('|',"")
```

print("""\n""")
print("Category: ", Category )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.get_text()` method instead of `.text` property

```
Category = soup.find('a', class_='article-labels__text b-reith-sans-font').get_text(strip=True)
```